# A control with ID could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, repeater

I have an update panel that has UpdateMode of Conditional and ChildrenAsTriggers set to false. I only want a few controls to cause an asynchronous postback:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnlMain" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
<ContentTemplate>

      // ...
      <asp:Repeater ID="rptListData" runat="server">
          <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Button ID="btnAddSomething" runat="server" OnClick="btnAddSomething_Click" />
          </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
      // ...
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAddSomething" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I am getting the following error when I try and load this page:

```
A control with ID 'btnAddSomething' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'updPnlMain'.
```

Since my btnAddSomething control is in a repeater and might not be there right away it acts like it is nonexistent. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because your control is in the `repeater control` and it is out of scope to the `Trigger collection`. By the way you don't need to `add trigger` because your button control is already in the `UpdatePanel`, it will update when you click the button.

**Edit:** There is a solution if you really want to update your updPnlMain updatepanel. You can put in another updatepanel and put your button in that panel. e.g.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updButton" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <asp:Button ID="btnAddSomething" runat="server" OnClick="btnAddSomething_Click" />
</ContentTemplate>
```

and then simply call the `updPnlMain.Update();` method in `btnAddSomething_Click` event.

It will actually do what you are looking for :)

Comment: Not if ChildrenAsTriggers=false...which is what I said in the question.

Comment: How can I get my repeater controls children to be in the scope then?

Comment: You only want to update your UpdatePanel updPnlMain, onclick of button ?

Comment: I want a few triggers. One of them is outside of the UpdatePanel. The other is the btnAddSomething button that is inside of the repeater. It is actually a LinkButton with the Command event in my real scenario however. I tried setting ChildrenAsTriggers="true" so I didn't have to specify the Triggers manually but even then the link button wasn't causing an async postback.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352866/how-to-prevent-full-page-postback-on-selectedindexchange-for-dropdownlist I don't know why my page is doing a full postback. Please help.