# Dropdownlist not updating in UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I created a simple page in which I have two dropdownlists inside a UpdatePanel. When the first Dropdownlist changes selection, it's suppose to update the list for the second dropdownlist, but it doesn't work, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I get the following error:
A control with the ID "ctl00 $ MainContent $ FunctionCombo" could not be found for the trigger in the UpdatePanel "HeadUpdatePanel".

Even so when I step through it finds it and is not null.
See this line:

```
DropDownList dd = (DropDownList)cph.FindControl("FunktionCombo");
```

But when it tries to apply the trigger than this error comes:

```
trigger.ControlID = cph.FindControl("FunktionCombo").UniqueID;
```

FYI: The masterpage has no content, just calling the TestPage!

Here is my Code for TestPage:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test.TestPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" />

    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="HeadUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Always" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Wähle Funktion:" />&nbsp;
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="FunktionCombo" OnSelectedIndexChanged="FunktionCombo_SelectionChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Wähle Tabelle:" />&nbsp;
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="TabelleCombo" OnSelectedIndexChanged="TabelleCombo_SelectionChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:Label ID="CountLbl" runat="server" Text="Wähle Funktion:" />
                    <asp:Button ID="StartBn" runat="server" Text="Start" onclick="StartBtn_Click" />
                </ContentTemplate>               
            </asp:UpdatePanel>            
        </div>        
    </div>
</asp:Content>


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class TestPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        private List<ViewInfo> _ospList;
        private List<ViewInfo> _aeList;
        private List<ViewInfo> _icList;

        private bool _functionChanged = false;
        private string _currentFunctionDisplay = "";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["IsAdmin"] = true;
                HttpContext.Current.Session["IsSubAdmin"] = true;

                CreateComboLists();

                ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("MainContent");
                UpdatePanelControlTrigger trigger = new PostBackTrigger();
                DropDownList dd = (DropDownList)cph.FindControl("FunktionCombo");
                trigger.ControlID = cph.FindControl("FunktionCombo").UniqueID;

                HeadUpdatePanel.Triggers.Add(trigger);
            }
        }

        private void CreateComboLists()
        {
            if ((bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["IsAdmin"] == true)
            {
                FunktionCombo.Items.Add("OSP");
                FunktionCombo.Items.Add("AE");
                FunktionCombo.Items.Add("IC");
                FunktionCombo.DataBind();
                FunktionCombo.SelectedIndex = 0;

                _ospList = GetSprocList("OSP", (HttpContext.Current.Session["IsAdmin"] != null) ? (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["IsAdmin"] : false, (HttpContext.Current.Session["IsSubAdmin"] != null) ? (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["IsSubAdmin"] : false);
                _aeList = GetSprocList("AE", (HttpContext.Current.Session["IsAdmin"] != null) ? (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["IsAdmin"] : false, (HttpContext.Current.Session["IsSubAdmin"] != null) ? (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["IsSubAdmin"] : false);
                _icList = GetSprocList("IC", (HttpContext.Current.Session["IsAdmin"] != null) ? (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["IsAdmin"] : false, (HttpContext.Current.Session["IsSubAdmin"] != null) ? (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["IsSubAdmin"] : false);

                TabelleCombo.DataSource = _ospList;
                TabelleCombo.DataTextField = "ViewName";
                TabelleCombo.DataValueField = "SprocName";
                TabelleCombo.SelectedIndex = 0;
                TabelleCombo.DataBind();
            }            
        }

        protected void FunktionCombo_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList obj = (DropDownList)sender;

            TabelleCombo.DataSource = null;
            _functionChanged = true;

            if (FunktionCombo.SelectedValue.ToString() == "OSP")
            {
                TabelleCombo.DataSource = _ospList;
                TabelleCombo.DataTextField = "ViewName";
                TabelleCombo.DataValueField = "SprocName";
                _currentFunctionDisplay = "OSP";
            }
            else if (FunktionCombo.SelectedValue.ToString() == "AE")
            {
                TabelleCombo.DataSource = _aeList;
                TabelleCombo.DataTextField = "ViewName";
                TabelleCombo.DataValueField = "SprocName";
                _currentFunctionDisplay = "AE";
            }
            else if (FunktionCombo.SelectedValue.ToString() == "IC")
            {
                TabelleCombo.DataSource = _icList;
                TabelleCombo.DataTextField = "ViewName";
                TabelleCombo.DataValueField = "SprocName";
                _currentFunctionDisplay = "IC";
            }

            TabelleCombo.DataBind();
            TabelleCombo.SelectedIndex = 0;
            SetCountText();
        }

        protected void TabelleCombo_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList obj = (DropDownList)sender;
        }

        private void SetCountText(string text = "")
        {
            CountLbl.Text = TabelleCombo.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }

        public static List<ViewInfo> GetSprocList(string function, bool isAdmin, bool isSubAdmin, bool infoPanel = false)
        {
            List<ViewInfo> sl = new List<ViewInfo>();

            switch (function)
            {
                case "OSP":
                    sl.Add(new ViewInfo("First Meetings Set", "sp_Activity_OSP_First"));
                    sl.Add(new ViewInfo("Contacts", "sp_Activity_OSP_Contact"));                   
                    return sl;

                case "AE":                    
                    sl.Add(new ViewInfo("Dials", "sp_Activity_AE_Dials"));
                    sl.Add(new ViewInfo("Dials Daily", "sp_Activity_AE_Dials_Daily"));
                    return sl;

                case "IC":
                    sl.Add(new ViewInfo("Monthly Activity Callstatus", "sp_Activity_IC_CallStatus"));
                    return sl;                

                default:
                    sl.Add(new ViewInfo("First Meetings Set", "sp_Activity_OSP_First"));
                    sl.Add(new ViewInfo("Contacts", "sp_Activity_OSP_Contact"));
                    return sl;
            }
        }
    }

    public class ViewInfo
    {
        public string ViewName { get; set; }
        public string SprocName { get; set; }
        public string ExtraName { get; set; }
        public List<ViewInfo> ViewList { get; set; }

        public ViewInfo()
        {
            this.ViewName = "";
            this.SprocName = "";
        }

        public ViewInfo(string name, string sproc, string extraName = "")
        {
            this.ViewName = name;
            this.SprocName = sproc;
            this.ExtraName = extraName;
        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Try and use breakpoints to check if the event for the dropdownlist selected index changes fires.

Comment: Please show the errors if any

Comment: I just added the error to the description

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A control with ID could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667398/a-control-with-id-could-not-be-found-for-the-trigger-in-updatepanel)

Comment: So when I use: trigger.ControlID = dd.ID;   it works and finds the control, but it doesn't update the Dropdown. I also added HeadUpdatePanel.Update(); to the bottom of FunktionCombo_SelectionChanged, but still does nothing???

Comment: OK, I found the issue, and I'm so sorry, as it was a stupid. When I applied the DataSource to the DDL, the list was null, as I forgot it will be deleted by postback. So I'm just creating the lists at runtime, and now it works. Again, sos sorry for that, but thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the issue, and I'm so sorry, as it was so stupid. 
First issue:
I deleted the trigger as it is not needed, since the DDL which triggers it, is inside the Updatepanel, which solved that issue.

Second issue:
When I applied the DataSource to the DDL inside of FunktionCombo_SelectionChanged, the list was null, as I forgot it will be deleted by postback.

So I'm just creating the lists at runtime, and now it works.

```
_ospList = SprocEvaluator.GetSprocList("OSP", (HttpContext.Current.Session["IsAdmin"] != null) ? (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["IsAdmin"] : false, (HttpContext.Current.Session["IsSubAdmin"] != null) ? (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["IsSubAdmin"] : false);
TabelleCombo.DataSource = _ospList;
```

Again, so sorry for that, but thanks for all the help!